# Hyperledge fabric VS code ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to begin to customise my own network on the hyperledger fabric by utilising VS code. So right now, I'm just trying to get the ansible examples to work found here (https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ansible-examples/tree/master/two-org-network).

But I keep encountering multiple errors. The third one I have encountered is this:

*TASK [ibm.blockchain_platform_manager : Enroll the user]

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "fabric-ca-client enroll -u 'https://admin:********@localhost:18050' --caname ca -M /Users/.../ansibelFiles/ansible-examples/two-org-network/wallets/Org1/admin --tls.certfiles /Users/.../ansibelFiles/ansible-examples/two-org-network/wallets/Org1/ca-tls-root.pem", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'fabric-ca-client'", "rc": 2}*

This is the 25th test that Ansible is performing.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

This error is just saying it cannot find the command `fabric-ca-client`. So make sure:

1. you have Hyperledger Fabric binaries installed ([installation guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html))
2. it is added to your shell environment `export PATH=<path to download location>/bin:$PATH`